# Tornado server won't use environment variable when 4 processes spawned

Tags: python, tornado

I have a Python web app using the Tornado framework.
It also uses the jaydebeapi package to connect to a database via JDBC.
This connection works fine when I try it from the virtual environment which has my environment variable for JAVA_HOME set.

I also declare the environment variable in the Python code itself at the start:

```
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'
```

I spawn 4 server processes like this (I have 4 cores):

```
server = HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(port)
server.start(0)  # forks one process per CPU
IOLoop.current().start()
```

But when I do so - the database connection never completes, it just hangs.
If I change server.start to (1), only a single process launches - and the database connection works fine.

Is there any way to pass the environment variable to the other processes that Tornado launches?  Is that in fact the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you be running an instance per core? I mean without forking.

Comment: I see nothing in your question that suggests this problem has to do with Java or JDBC; I have removed those tags.

Comment: Are you doing anything else before calling `start(0)`? Starting java subprocesses, perhaps?